# Visio connector labels at the start of a connector line rather than the middle

Tags: visio

Can I **configure** a Visio diagram so that the labels on connectors, by default, appear at the beginning of the line rather than the middle.

I know that text labels can be moved by the "text block" tool (accessed using Shift-Ctrl-4); I'm talking about changing the default behaviour of the Visio diagram.

In the case of a flowchart diagram decision box, it makes far more sense (to me) to have the labels at the beginning of a line.

Answer (score 3):

The normal behaviour of the Dynamic connector and similar masters, is that the text block position is positioned by the Controls.TextPosition X and Y values.
[Normal Dynamic connector text position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4xhE.png)
Therefore, you can edit your "Dynamic connector" master in the Document stencil to default the text block at the start of the line by setting Controls.TextPosition.X and Y to 0